Is it possible to determine the magnification of a compound microscope given the objective focal length, eyepiece focal length, and objective di?
Question as stated above, I want to know if it is possible to determine the magnification of the microscope from the objective and eyepiece focal lengths, and image distance of the objective lens. this isn't a homework question, I'm just curious to know if this particular configuration can be used to find the total magnification.
